# 80K rows mysql users table cause login problems

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I've a large users table on my database with 80k users which cause mostly login problems.

I have a solution! Don't know whether it's a good one or not!

I want to create other users tables for new users and save last IP of them in it.

So in most cases of login **by knowing Ip range** I can redirect users to the right table in login. If it's not the right table then it will check other tables.

So I think it will increase speed!

Is it a good solution!? I will be appreciated if anyone come up with a **better solution**!

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3nOY.png)

Comment: 80K is not large so you must be having some other problems, like lack of indexing. Show us the table configuration.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have an id field which is index! so I'm afraid maybe it's not about indexing! which other things may cause problem!?

Comment: I agree with @Jay Blanchard 80k isn't really that much for a correctly set up database. Convert to INNODB if not already and add indexes to columns used in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: So do users login using their `id`, or do they have a "user name"?

Comment: Just because the id field is indexed doesn't mean it is indexed correctly. Show us the table configuration and how you query the table.

Comment: We ordinarily use the word *huge* for tables with something like a billion rows. You have a *small* user table. You probably need an index on the user name.

Comment: ID is not likely used in `WHERE` for login.. Index username/pasword.. the ones your login function uses in `WHERE`

Comment: I added a photo of table description! 
Guys you are right about using word "huge"! My mistake!

Comment: A unique index on email would likely help (assuming email is used in the WHERE clause for login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good solution!?

No, it is not a good solution. It is, in fact, a terrible solution.

From your table definition, we can guess that your users give their email addresses to log in.

Try creating an index on that column.

```
 ALTER TABLE ci_users ADD INDEX index_email (email);
```

Once you do that, queries of the form

```
 SELECT something FROM ci_users WHERE email = 'user-supplied-value'
```

and

```
 SELECT something FROM ci_users WHERE email LIKE 'user-supplied-value%'
```

will start to be very fast, almost as if by magic. That's DBMS technology at work.

You should read about indexing. http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good source.

If you will have some users supplying a phone number, and others providing a email address, you need two *different* indexes, one for each.

A typical table can have as many indexes as you need.  With a table that size, you can create them easily without disrupting production. But don't create indexes until you know you need them.

Comment: yes exactly by email and soon by mobile phone number and email!
will indexing another column may cause conflicts or side effects?!
Thanks by the way!

Comment: For that I would suggest an index on email and an index on email and phone

Comment: indexing was a great solution!
worked for me!
Thanks guys